# tinyMCE: set padding of editor

Tags: tinymce

How do I set the padding inside the tinyMCE editor?

I've seen answers like so:

```
body{ padding:0px }
```

But it shouldn't be on the body??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have look at the tinymce config param [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css). Using this param you may set your own css stuff and overwrite tinymcedefault css. You may apply the padding to whatever element you want (under body)

Comment: Perfect (turned out it was margin that I needed to change to get it flush with the border)

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 5):

you could also try these methods:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML

  // set whatever class name you have that adds the padding
  body_class: 'my_class', 

  // or attach your own css file (resolved to http://domain/myLayout.css)
  content_css : '/myLayout.css',

  // or finally, add your padding directly
  content_style: "body {padding: 10px}"
});
```

see the [docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/) for more info

Comment: new documentation link: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/

Answer (score 2):

If you need a quick solution try the CSS definition:

```
div.mce-edit-area{
    background:#FFF;
    filter:none;
>>> padding:10px; <<< 
}
```

in the **skin.min.css** and **skin.ie7.min.css** files.

Comment: I put this in my custom css file (defined via content_css) and it works perfectly. Nice and easy hack!